# Big Query How to fill the cell value with the value from previous row

Tags: google-bigquery

In BQ I have a table like this, and I would like to fill the Id_customer empty cells with values from row above.

[image]

Comment: having input data as in y our question - please show expected result

Comment: the gray cells should be filled with the value above 2334

Answer (score -1):

```
with grouped_table as (
   select date,
          day_of_week,
          inventory,
          count(inventory) over (order by date) as _grp
   from inventory_log
), final_table as(
   select date,
          day_of_week,
          inventory,
          _grp,
          first_value() over (partition by _grp order by date) as
              new_inventory
    from grouped_table
)
select date,
       day_of_week,
       new_inventory
from final_table
```

https://medium.com/towards-data-science/tips-and-tricks-how-to-fill-null-values-in-sql-4fccb249df6f

Comment: I'm not convinced, the op shows multiple rows with the same rowid, it smells like code_product is a nested structure, not actually separate rows. (besides, your code has no relation to the table in the question, and you gave no parameter to FIRST_VALUE()...)